# JS How to include a variable inside an image's path?

Tags: javascript

I am using google maps api to display some points on a map. I need each marker to appear on the map with different icon depending on its type. For example houses a red dot and stores a blue dot. The type is pointed out by a variable "exacttype" .
Right now there is a variable `var icon` that includes the path like this `icon.image='....apath/iconred.png';`
How can i include this variable in the icons path so i wont need to create a different icon variable? something like this : `icon.image='...apth/icon"exacttype".png;`
The reason i am doing this is i already have 2 types of icons A and B but lets say icons A do need to differentiate from eachother according to their details.

Comment: url parameters ie) `?exacttype=typestr` at the end of the url as you would with any url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
icon.image = '....apath/iconred.png'
icon.image = icon.image.replace(/icon[^.]+(?=[.]png)/, 'icon' + exacttype);
```

In other word, you replace 'icon' and all non-dot symbols that follow it with concatenation of 'icon' and that string stored in `exacttype` variable. It could be made even more concise with  help of look-behind expression `/(?<=icon)[^.]+(?=[.]png)/`, but JS does not support it.